# query not returning expected result?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables:

1)report_details

[image: report_details]

2) reports

[image]

**Query :**

```
SELECT COUNT(channel),DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS niceDate,
    channel FROM `report_details`
JOIN report on report.report_id=report_details.report_id
where report.report_hash='abcd'
GROUP BY  channel,niceDate;
```

**output**

[image]

**expected output**

[image]

Comment: When asking for help, please keep it straightforward and to-the-point. Messages like "please help me" and sad-face emoticons are forms of begging, which is not ideal when approaching volunteers. Ideally, if you can explain what you have tried to solve your problem, that is a good as well - we get a lot of people here every day who try something for five minutes and then give up shortly afterwards. Don't be that person!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem** :
as far as i can see there is a problem in your query, it seems you will need more than a simple group by since you want an aggregation. So you probably want to use GROUP_CONCAT() to to get your chanels, but you will need an inner select if you want to group all chanels of the same date on 1 line but with separator

**Modified query** :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cnt),niceDate,GROUP_CONCAT(channel)channel FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(channel) as cnt ,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y')
  AS  niceDate,group_concat(channel) channel
  FROM `report_details` JOIN report on report.report_id=report_details.report_id
  where report.report_hash='abcd' GROUP BY  chanel,niceDate
) f
GROUP BY niceDate ;
```

**Explication**

- I put the first query as an inner select so that you could have all chanels of the same date on 1 line, you can't do it in 1 select since Group_Concat can't have a count inside unless it comes from an inner select like in this example
- I added the use of group_concat(chanel) so that you get the list of chanel and not separate line for each of them

if you want more information on group_concat here is the link to the doc :
[Documentation](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: count is not getting properly

Comment: @midhunk I updated the code with an inner select so tell me if it works

Answer (score 2):

```
 $value =  DB::table('report_details')
 ->join('reports','report_details.report_id','=','reports.report_id')
 ->groupBy('channel')->get();

// print_r($value);
 also use DB; in your controller
```

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This appears to be a Laravel answer for a SQL question?

Comment: @halfer To be fair, the question _is_ tagged with Laravel as well

Comment: @ChrisForrence: true, but the OP does seem to be trying SQL, so while this may help, it doesn't explain the OP's problem `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COUNT),GROUP_CONCAT(channel)channel,niceDate FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(channel)COUNT, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS niceDate,channel 
    FROM `report_details` 
    JOIN report ON report.report_id = report_details.report_id 
    WHERE report.report_hash = 'abcd' 
    GROUP BY niceDate,channel 
)Z
GROUP BY niceDate ;
```

Comment: @Chris Where is my other statement  is??

Comment: Please don't add "hope this helps" to your answers - since no-one ever hopes it _doesn't help_, it is completely redundant. You seem to have added this [to 219 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5809720+hope+this+helps), which is a lot of clean-up for a volunteer editor to do.

Comment: @SagarGangwal The language used ("...can try above...", "Hope this will help") weakens your answer; it makes it seem like more of a guess.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Okey Chris i got it..!! **Special Thanks**